# Is “semisimplification” a 2-functor?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories, 2-categories

Consider the following 2-category $\mathcal K$:

- objects are finite length abelian categories (i.e., abelian categories where every object has finite length)
- morphisms are exact functors (preserving finite length)
- 2-morphisms are all natural transformations.

For every finite length abelian category $\mathcal C$, we have a new finite length abelian category $\mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}}$, namely the full subcategory of $\mathcal C$ spanned by the semisimple objects.

**Question:** Does the assignment
$$
\mathcal C \mapsto \mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}}
$$
extend to a 2-functor $\Phi\colon \mathcal K \to \mathcal K$?

**My thoughts:** There is a natural functor $(\cdot)^{\mathrm{ss}} \colon \mathcal C \to \mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}}$ for every $\mathcal C$ in $\mathcal K$ given by semisimplification. (It is, of course, not adjoint to the inclusion.) So if you have a morphism $F\colon \mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ in $\mathcal K$, you get a new functor $F^{\mathrm{ss}} \colon \mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}} \to \mathcal D^{\mathrm{ss}}$ via the composition $\mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}} \subseteq \mathcal C \xrightarrow{F} \mathcal D \xrightarrow{(\cdot)^{\mathrm{ss}}} \mathcal D^{\mathrm{ss}}$. From this it is also clear how $\Phi$ should be defined on 2-morphisms.

The problem I have is that, given another morphism $G\colon \mathcal D\to \mathcal E$ in $\mathcal K$, it is not clear to me how to construct a natural isomorphism
$$
G^{\mathrm{ss}} \circ F^{\mathrm{ss}} \cong (G\circ F)^{\mathrm{ss}}.
$$
To be clear: for each object $c$ of $\mathcal C$, one has $G^{\mathrm{ss}}(F^{\mathrm{ss}}(c)) \cong (G\circ F)^{\mathrm{ss}}(c)$ (by inspection), and my problem is to see how this isomorphism could be made natural in $c$.

If my question has a positive answer, I would be grateful for a reference or a proof. If not, then a counterexample would be nice.

Comment: How is the functor $(\cdot)^{\mathrm{ss}}$ defined? Maybe you want some extra restrictions on your category $\mathcal{C}$, but if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of finite $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules then that is a finite length abelian category, and $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{ss}$ is the category of finite $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-modules, but there are no nonzero exact functors $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{ss}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you for the comment. The functor $(\cdot)^{\mathrm{ss}}$ is given by semisimplification: it is the composite $\mathcal C \to \mathrm{Filt}(\mathcal C) \to \mathrm{Grad}(\mathcal C) \to \mathcal C$. Here, $\mathrm{Filt}(\mathcal C)$ (resp. $\mathrm{Grad}(\mathcal C)$) is the category of filtered (resp. graded) objects in $\mathcal C$. The first functor sends an objects to its socle filtration, the second functor is the associated graded, and the third forgets the filtration. The essential image is $\mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, I don't understand why in your example there are no non-zero exact functors $\mathcal C\to \mathcal C^{\mathrm{ss}}$. Could you say a word about why that is?

Comment: To save typing, I'll write $Z_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. If $F$ were such a functor, and $F(Z_2)\cong Z_2^r$, then from the short exact sequence obtained by applying $F$ to $0\to Z_2\to Z_4\to Z_2\to0$, $F(Z_4)\cong Z_2^{2r}$. But F must send the map $Z_4\xrightarrow{\times 2}Z_4$ to zero, so from the exact sequence obtained by applying $F$ to $Z_4\xrightarrow{\times 2}Z_4\to Z_2\to0$, $F(Z_4)$ must be isomorphic to $Z_2^r$.

Comment: But, come to think of it, you probably don't care whether $(\cdot)^{\mathrm{ss}}$ is exact, as $F^\mathrm{ss}$ will still be exact because $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{ss}$ is semisimple.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, thank you for the nice explanation!